# Unable to start the daemon process. error still exists

Tags: android

[i have added the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHL5q.jpg)i got this error while using android studio ,i did try changing org.gradle.jvmargs to 1024m but it didnt work neither did deleting the .gradle file and starting android studio again, i also tried removing all the files n then reinstalling it but it also didnt work can anybody pls help me out

Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Comment: can you make a screenshot of the error?

Comment: If you have antivirus programs (Avast, AVG Free Antivirus) running please turn off it. Check for `adb.exe` file in virus chest. If you find it please restore it again

Comment: i use windows 10 ,android studio version 3.1.2 and gradle version 4.4

Comment: @Shashanth  i checked the antivirus it hasnt blocked anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, i also tried many ways. And after i uninstalled Connectify me program, it worked. So i think you can try to uninstall some programs you have just installed. Sorry for my English.